# buttons in a datagrid in flex

Tags: apache-flex, flash, flex3, flash-cs3

i am using a data grid in flex and i am generating data from a mysql server. However, my problem is with adding a button within the datagrid so each row has one.

i have set the columns itemRenderer to mx.controls.Button although with the buttons shown in the grid there is no label on them (even though one has been set) and the assigned click event does not trigger when hitting the button. anyone have any ideas or guidance on what i am doing wrong.
Thanks
Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not to worry I have sorted it. anyone with a similar issue i suggest reading this
http://www.axelscript.com/2008/02/29/using-the-itemrenderer-with-a-datagrid-in-flex/

an excellent source.